# What is the purpose of postcss-autoreset and postcss-initial

Tags: css, postcss

What is the purpose for:

- [PostCSS Autoreset](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-autoreset)
- [PostCSS Initial](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-initial)

The documentation is very sparse on both and doesn't really explain why one should use them and what there purpose is.

I've tried autoreset. It seems to place `all: initial` on every element you style. This seems very wasteful when looking at the output.

How is it any different from:

```
* {
    all: initial,
    font-family: "Roboto"
}
```

Looking at the code for autoreset it seems to do just that: https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-autoreset/blob/master/src/resetRules.es6

I don't get why this is better than using `*`

Answer (score 4):

`postcss-autoreset` protects your from inherited properties in CSS.

Imagine that you wrote a component and publish it to npm. You used BEM or CSS Modules, so selectors are isolated. But some developer took your component to webpage with:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 2
}
```

Because of non-default `box-sizing` all your sizes become broken. Because os non-standard `line-height` text become bigger and broke design.

Here is a real example of such issue in [EmojiMart](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart/issues/24#issuecomment-261264594) component.

`postcss-autoreset` will put a `all: initial` to every selector in your component CSS:

```
.component {
  all: initial; /* added by postcss-autoreset, you didn’t write it */
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.component_title {
  all: initial; /* added by postcss-autoreset, you didn’t write it */
  height: 20px;
}
```

As result this auto-inserted `all: initial` disable user `box-sizing` and `line-height` in your component and your component looks in same way in user website.

Comment: But if I use bootstrap, autoreset will wipe bootstrap's styles too? Does it mean, that autoreset is useful for isolated components, but there is no reason to use it for usual site developent?

Answer (score 0):

This is better than `*` when you want to create isolable component, meaning component that you can integrate in other people app or website like a plug-in or add-on.